# I can't import *.h files after importing projects using CocoaPods

Tags: cocoapods

I need to introduce another tool in the project, but after importing according to the code they provided, I can't import the *.h file. This problem has been bothering me for three days. The usage environment is pod 1.8.0, xcoder 10.2.1. .

https://github.com/zhangdan183/DemoProject

I want to use pod to introduce the tools in the following address in this project, but after the introduction UZApp/ZUZModules/ModuleDemo/ModuleDemo/UZModuleDemo.h can not introduce Logan.h, after adding ${PODS_ROOT} no effect, no Know that there are no other issues.

Comment: Could you show us the code, please?

Comment: This is my project address： https://github.com/zhangdan183/DemoProject